# "You can dance however you like." --- Is the sentence as idiomatic as "You can dance any way you like."

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

**"You can dance any way you like."**

**"You can dance however you like."**

The both mean the same to me, at least in terms of grammer. Are they both idiomatic, too?

Comment: Yes, "however you like" or "however you wish" or "however you care to" are all idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are idiomatic. "however you like" is a tad towards the formal/educated end of the spectrum.  "any way" is colloquial.